# In Java, how to properly call the Arrays class methods?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

EDIT: Seriously, what's with the downvotes? I thought I described my issue with adequate details and researched this fairly well before posting even if I wasn't able to find the answer on my own.

There is a built-in Arrays class in Java that has some useful methods for arrays, like binarysearch() and sort(), but for some reason I can't figure out how to call its methods correctly. I'm trying to search inside an array for a specific string, and I want to return the index if found, so I tried this:

```
int rankID = Arrays.binarysearch(cardRanks, myRank);
```

Where "cardRanks" is my array and "myRank" is my passed in string parameter that I want to search for. I also tried this (although I suspect this returns a boolean rather than an integer):

```
int rankID = Arrays.asList(cardRanks).contains(myRank);
```

Whenever I try any of these I get this same error at compile:

```
Error: cannot find symbol
symbol:   variable Arrays
```

This error is basically telling me that the compiler doesn't recognize "Arrays" as the class and is treating it like a variable.

From what I understand there isn't any "#include" type statement in Java, which was my first guess, and so I'm assuming that the built-in classes are just included (although this would be the source of my trouble if my assumption is wrong). I've looked up several tutorials on arrays and questions on forums about binarysearch() and the Arrays class (which is how I found out about the "aslist.contains" part) but  I haven't been able to find this answer.

What am I doing wrong? What is the proper way to call the Arrays class methods? Is there another way to tell the compiler that I want to use the java.util.Arrays library?

This is the rest of the code I'm using in this particular class, in case the error lies elsewhere in my code:

```
class PlayingCards {
    private static String[] cardRanks = {"Ace","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","Jack","Queen","King"};
    private static String[] cardSuits = {"spades", "hearts", "clubs", "diamonds"};
    private String rank;
    private String suit;

    public PlayingCards (String myRank, String mySuit) {
        //rank = myRank;
        suit = mySuit;
        int rankID = Arrays.binarysearch(cardRanks, myRank);
        System.out.println("Rank found and is index: " + rankID);
        rank = cardRanks[rankID];
        System.out.println("Associated rank is: " + rank);
    }


    public PlayingCards (int myRank, int mySuit) {
        rank = this.cardRanks[myRank];
        suit = PlayingCards.cardSuits[mySuit];
    }

    public PlayingCards () {
        rank = "Ace";
        suit = "spades";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Draw some cards!");
        PlayingCards card1 = new PlayingCards("King","diamonds");
        //PlayingCards card2 = new PlayingCards("5","monkeys");
        PlayingCards card3 = new PlayingCards(1,0);
        PlayingCards card4 = new PlayingCards();

        System.out.println("Your 1st card is: a " + card1.rank + " of " + card1.suit + ".");
        //System.out.println("Your 2nd card is: a " + card2.rank + " of " + card2.suit + ".");
        System.out.println("Your 3rd card is: a " + card3.rank + " of " + card3.suit + ".");
        System.out.println("Your 4th card is: a " + card4.rank + " of " + card4.suit + ".");
    }
}
```

When I run this code with the offending lines commented out and just accepting the given rank and suit strings without checking against the array, everything works fine, so I don't think I did anything wrong in my array declarations (because I can pull out the correct entry when I use the constructor that looks up rank and suit by array index). Any tips or help would be greatly appreciated!

I'm actually stepping through the official Java "trail" tutorials and I've been looking all over for some kind of examples or in-depth explanation of working with arrays but there is almost no information. Maybe this is just a much more advanced topic that isn't intended for beginners?

Comment: `import java.util.Arrays;`

Comment: *"Maybe this is just a much more advanced topic that isn't intended for beginners?"* - I think the problem is the opposite; imports are so basic that the tutorial may have assumed that was known.

Comment: I don't think this question deserves downvotes, by the way. It may be a trivial question but it *is* well-stated. If only every question on this site was as clear and full of relevant information as this one.

Comment: I was guessing that the tutorial was supposed to go from the basics on up, but maybe they just missed that part. And thanks for the kudos for my question - I didn't want to bother anyone with a stupid question but it looks like I did anyway. I don't have a lot of points to lose in the first place, heh.

Comment: @AliumBritt Yeah, looking at the [full trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/TOC.html), they put packages at the end. I can see where the confusion comes from. They may also be assuming that you're using some IDE that automagically inserts import statements (or suggests import statements) for you (e.g. NetBeans or Eclipse).

Comment: @JasonC That's probably be what happened - I'm using DrJava, which was the suggested IDE for my algorithms class. I do have Eclipse also, but I haven't played around with it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to import it:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
```

At the top of your file.

Alternatively, you can refer to it by its fully qualified name without importing it, e.g. `java.util.Arrays.asList(cardRanks)`.

Only `java.lang.*` is imported automatically (well, and the package your class itself is in as well); everything else you have to import explicitly.

Note also that [`Arrays.binarySearch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%29) requires your input array to be pre-sorted in ascending order to work correctly.

Comment: Thanks! I'm choosing this one since it has a very thorough explanation.

Comment: Does the import line have to be the first line in the class?

Comment: @AliumBritt Yes. The only line that can come before it is a [`package` declaration](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/createpkgs.html) if you're writing packages. Check out the [official tutorial on importing packages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html) (which, sadly, is the very last section of the language basics trail).

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the `import` statement at the begining of your class:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
```